# VSCode TreeItem - right click option off a right click option

Tags: visual-studio-code, treeview, vscode-extensions

I have a Treeview that extends to 3 levels. On the 3rd child node level, I have a right click option that then displays 6 or 7 options. That is all working fine.

However, I want to add a few more right click options and rather than end up with as may as 10 options, I would like to group the 3 new options into a single category option such that when it is clicked - or right clicked, the 3 new options then appear. I think this would be much better than displaying as many as 10 options.
Is this even possible to have a right click on a tree node that the displayed option then itself can have a right click?

I have searched but not found anything to suggest that this is doable.